# Vlookup VBA failure

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

So I have this code I use at work, when I am using my code, it returns only the first value of the vlookup, the second one isn't on the table so it doesn't give me anything but the next one that is on the table doesn't appear.

Here is my code

```
Sub Modify()
'Created by Fernando Almada 9/26/2017
On Error Resume Next

Sheet14.Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
Sheet14.Range(Columns(4), Columns(8)).EntireColumn.Delete

Sheet14.Range("d1").Value = "Cost"
Sheet14.Range("c1").Copy
Sheet14.Range("d1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Sheet14.Cells.Select
With Selection
.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With
Selection.Columns.AutoFit
Dim myrange As Range

Tagg = Sheet1.Range("E3:N190")
Lrow = Sheet14.Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Select
Set myrange = Sheet14.Range(ActiveCell, Cells(2, 1))

Dept_Row = Sheet14.Range("d2").Row
Dept_Clm = Sheet14.Range("d2").Column

For Each cl In myrange

  Sheet14.Cells(Dept_Row, Dept_Clm) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Tagg, 8, False)
  Dept_Row = Dept_Clm + 1

Next cl



End Sub
```

Please help me!

Comment: *the second one isn't on the table so it doesn't give me anything but the next one that is on the table doesn't appear.* - what?

Comment: Can you also add sample data to support this?

Answer (score 0):

To start with, I would use `Option Explicit`. Second, because of the `On Error Resume Next`, you miss a lot of messages MsExcel could give you during execution of the macro. A list of specific remarks :

- in order to use `Tagg` as a range, I have to use `Set` : 
  `Dim Tagg as Range`
  `Set Tagg = Sheet1.Range("E3:N190")`
- Replacing `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` by `Application.VLookup` will return a text like `Error 8888` in your cell instead of halting execution.
- I do not understand `Dept_Row = Dept_Clm + 1`, perhaps `Dept_Row = Dept_Row + 1` ?